# SQL - Coulmn headers as rows (for both 0's and 1's)

Tags: sql

Please help, I have a table like this :

```
ID  HCC1    HCC2    HCC3    HCC4
101 0   1   1   0
102 0   0   1   0
103 0   0   0   0
```

I want the resulting table to look like this:

```
ID  HCC
101 HCC2
101 HCC3
102 HCC3
103 0
```

If a member has 1 in multiple HCC's , both need to be listed in separate rows (for instance ID-101). If member has 0 in all HCC's then there should be 0 in HCC column (for instance ID-103). I tried "unpivot" but it works only for 1's, I need 0's too.

I have 150 such column headers and 100,000 ID's

Thank You!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Many RDBMSs supports operators or expressions which might be a bit simpler or perform a lott better.  However, they are not a standard operation and the syntax varies wildly between vendors.  The UNION ALL version Gordon answered with is really the only standard SQL method.

Comment: PLEASE tell us WHICH database you actually use!  "SQL" isn't enough to tell us what features might be available. ALWAYS include the dbms you use as a tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `union all`:

```
select id, 'HCC1' as hcc from t where hcc1 = 1 union all
select id, 'HCC2' as hcc from t where hcc2 = 1 union all
select id, 'HCC3' as hcc from t where hcc3 = 1 union all
select id, 'HCC4' as hcc from t where hcc4 = 1 union all
select id, '0' as hcc from t where hcc1 = 0 and hcc2 = 0 and hcc3 = 0 and hcc4 = 0;
```

This is standard SQL.  Specific databases might have other methods or short-cuts.

Comment: Gordon, I edited post to add : I have 150 such column header's and 100,000 ID's.

Comment: @slqq . . . So you need 151 subqueries.

Comment: @slqq First normal form was either broken when designing the table (with HCC1 to HCC151 being a huge repeating group) or you're breaking first normal form with this query (by forcing data intended to represent different attributes into one column).  No matter how you do it, it's going to suck to write the query because you're crossing over that first rule of design to do it.  These are the consequences of not following that design.

Comment: Bacon Bits, I get this data from SAS and load it to SQL.

Comment: @slqq I understand.  I'm not saying *you* did anything wrong.  I'm just explaining why it seems so painful or complicated to do what you're doing.

Comment: @slqq I tossed together a script to generate your 151 subqueries. You can see it, and its output, here. __edit:__ moved HCC to upper case: https://3v4l.org/jXNAW

Comment: Thank You RToyota. That helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is **only** applicable if the dbms is MS SQL Server (or perhaps other platforms supporting the "apply operator" and that allow `values`). A script could be built to generate the ~150 case expressions (or use Excel) but the advantage here is that there is just one pass through the source table.

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3761f/1) (**MS SQL Server**)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [HCC1] int, [HCC2] int, [HCC3] int, [HCC4] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [HCC1], [HCC2], [HCC3], [HCC4])
VALUES
    (101, 0, 1, 1, 0),
    (102, 0, 0, 1, 0),
    (103, 0, 0, 0, 0)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
      id, ca.HCC
FROM table1
CROSS APPLY (
  values
       (case when HCC1+HCC2+HCC3+HCC4 = 0 then '0' end)
     , (case when HCC1 = 1 then 'HCC1' end)
     , (case when HCC2 = 1 then 'HCC2' end)
     , (case when HCC3 = 1 then 'HCC3' end)
   ) ca(HCC)
WHERE ca.hcc IS NOT NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3761f/1/0)**:

```
|  id |  HCC |
|-----|------|
| 101 | HCC2 |
| 101 | HCC3 |
| 102 | HCC3 |
| 103 |    0 |
```

if nothing else, perhaps this dbms specific answer will prompt you to add which dbms is actually being used.